# Cross-platform (JavaScript) tools for taming complexity of web pages?

Tags: javascript, html

What are the platform-independent tools for managing the complexity of developing (interactive) web pages?

I came across

[Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) -  "models with key-value binding and custom events ...views with declarative event handling, and connects it ...over a RESTful JSON interface"

[Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/) - a language that extends CSS, to easily manage styles. It compiles to CSS before rendering.

---

What are the other tools that are available on all major platforms and does the heavy lifting of developing web pages?

Comment: There's always Dreamweaver ;) lol

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com) :-)

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general purpose development: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

For MVVM pattern, data-binding, observables, etc. etc.

[KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/)